# Repeat each member by its key value in a dictionary without using np.repeat?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a simple dictionary of numbers and their respective frequencies that I made combining  two lists:

```py
elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
frequency = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

combined = {ele: freq for ele, freq in zip(elements, frequency)}

>>> print(combined)
{1: 5, 2: 4, 3: 3, 4: 2, 5: 1}
```

Now I would like each `ele` to be repeated by its `freq` and be saved in a new list. Ideally, the best would be to use `repeat()` from numpy.

```py
repeated = list(np.repeat(key, val) for key, val in sorted(combined.items()))  # If a dict needs sorting

>>> print(repeated)
[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2, ... ,4,4,5]
```

However, I would like to do this **without** using repeat. What would be a good way to proceed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way using `collections.Counter`:

```
d = {1: 5, 2: 4, 3: 3, 4: 2, 5: 1}
list(Counter(d).elements())
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
[i for ix, i in enumerate(elements) for f in range(frequency[ix])]
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

Or using generators:

```
frequency = iter([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
[i for i in elements for _ in range(next(frequency))]
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this list comprehension:

```py
repeated = [key for key, val in sorted(combined.items()) for _ in range(val)]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just `itertools.chain` to flatten a nested list of lists:

```
>>> nested = [[i] * j for (i, j) in zip(elements, frequency)]
>>> nested
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4], [5]]

>>> list(itertools.chain(*nested))
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

A nested list comprehension would work.

```
>>> x = [item for sublist in [[k]*v for k,v in combined.items()] for item in sublist]
>>> x
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

The inner list comprehension `[[k]*v for k,v in combined.items()]` will generate `[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4], [5]]`.

Here we use list multiplication to generate the multiples `[1]*5 >> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`.

The outer list comprehension, will flatten the former to get the final result.